In degenerate perturbation theory why can we assume that matrix elements above and below the degenerate subspace disappear?
The picture shows some original Hamiltonian H which has some degeneracies. Suppose I have some perturbation V to the system and I want to find the new energies and eigenstates of the system. Then from degenerate PT, my understanding is I diagonalise V in each subspace, in the diagram I've chosen the one with energy $\epsilon_2$, and I have the freedom to choose any eigenbasis spanned by the states in this degenerate block as the original Hamiltonian H will remain diagonal within this subspace always, as it is proportional to the identity. So the resulting Hamiltonian, given by the sum of H and V will therefore be diagonal within this block.
My issue is I'm not sure how to get rid of matrix elements that might be outside of this degenerate block. I've denoted these by the rectangles above and below the squared area. Do I approach this with non-degenerate perturbation theory?


I don't understand the question. If your Hamiltonian is $H'=H +\lambda V$ you first diagonalize $H$ and find that there is a sector with a degenerate eigenvalue. Hence by definition the matrix elements denoted by rectangles in your picture are zero in the eigenbasis.

Your $H$ is not block diagonal.

I think your problem would be simpler if you explicitly broke it down to
$$
H=H_0 + \lambda H^\prime_0+\lambda H_1
$$
where $H_0$ is already diagonal.  In your example:
$$
H_0=\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon_1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0 &\epsilon_2&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&\epsilon_2&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&\epsilon_2&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\epsilon_2&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\epsilon_3&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&\epsilon_3\\
\end{pmatrix}\, .
$$
The matrix $\lambda H_0^\prime$ is a block diagonal matrix containing entries in the $4\times 4$ subspace of vectors with eigenvalues $\epsilon_2$ of $H_0$,  and the $2\times 2$ subspace of vectors with eigenvalues $\epsilon_3$ of $H_0$.  Thus, $\lambda H_0^\prime$ has the form
$$
\lambda H_0^\prime=
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0 &*&*&*&*&0&0\\
0 &*&*&*&*&0&0\\
0 &*&*&*&*&0&0\\
0 &*&*&*&*&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&*&*\\
0&0&0&0&0&*&*\\
\end{pmatrix}\, .
$$
where $*$ denote non-zero entries, not necessarily identical, located to indicate the shapes of the degenerate subspaces.
Finally, the matrix $\lambda H_1^\prime$ will generally have non-zero entries connecting the subspaces; it is of the general form
$$
\lambda H_1^\prime=
\begin{pmatrix}\ast&\ast&\ast&\ast&\ast&\ast&\ast\\ \ast&0&0&0&0&\ast&\ast\\
\ast &0&0&0&0&\ast&\ast\\
\ast &0&0&0&0&\ast&\ast\\
\ast &0&0&0&0&\ast&\ast\\
\ast &\ast&\ast&\ast&\ast&0&0\\
\ast &\ast&\ast&\ast&\ast&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\, . \tag{1}
$$
Basically, you have broken up your perturbation into two parts: one that acts inside each degenerate subspace, and one that acts in between the degenerate subspaces.  The procedure is then as you suggest: because any linear combination of vectors with eigenvalue $\epsilon_2$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\epsilon_2$, you use this freedom to make a change of basis $T$ so $\lambda H_0^\prime\to  \lambda T H_0^\prime T^{-1}$ is diagonal, and use this new basis to proceed with the transformed $\lambda TH_1^\prime T^{-1}$ using regular perturbation theory. Note that the change of basis induces a change in $H_1^\prime$ so that  $\lambda TH_1^\prime T^{-1}$ can have in general non-zero entries at different places than in (1).
The assumption here is that no eigenvalues in $H_0+\lambda  T H_0^\prime T^{-1}$ are repeated, else the perturbation approach fails, in the sense that you cannot get second order corrections using the standard perturbation theory.  If some eigenvalues of $H_0+\lambda  T H_0^\prime T^{-1}$ are repeated, you might get lucky with the form of $\lambda TH_1^\prime T^{-1}$ and still be able to proceed, but this would be an exception rather than a general case.

Many thanks for the detailed response. To check my understanding, so the problem after constructing H_0' will be to let H_0 + H_0' be our new 'original' diagonal Hamiltonian with known spectrum and corresponding eigenstates, such that we no longer have any degeneracies in our eigenvalues. Then we carry out normal non-degenerate perturbation theory with H_1' as our perturbing Hamiltonian, where there won't be any first order corrections within the degenerate subspaces by construction of H_0' to take all the diagonal elements?

And also, you mention that we assume the perturbing Hamiltonian is able to break all the degeneracies of our original system s.t. we can apply the second order perturbative approach with H_1'. I'm still new to PT so the only examples I've looked through in much detail are the Zeeman and Stark effects for the bulk Hydrogen atom. In both cases we leave some degeneracies behind and 'get lucky' with H_1 = 0. But in the more general case where some degeneracies remain and the perturbing Hamiltonian has some matrix elements outside of the degenerate subspace, I assume it's no trivial matter to fix?

I don't remember immediately but there are remaining degeneracies  with the Stark effect in hydrogen for $n=2$ states.  When this is the case,  you have to use other methods to proceed.  Admittedly I don't have the details at my fingertips.


The picture shows some original Hamiltonian H which has some degeneracies. Suppose I have some perturbation V to the system and I want to find the new energies and eigenstates of the system.
...
My issue is I'm not sure how to get rid of matrix elements that might be outside of this degenerate block.

The thing you drew a picture of and are calling "some original Hamiltonian" appears to be what people would usually call $H_0$, i.e., the unperturbed hamiltonian.
The unperturbed hamiltonian is assumed to be diagonalizable, therefore you do not have to worry about getting rid of matrix elements off the diagonal.

...Then from degenerate PT, my understanding is I diagonalise V in each subspace...

This gives you the first-order correction, yes.
